# rails 4 multiple date ranges in one record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I need to add multiple different `start_time` and `end_time` dates to this model:

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :courses do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.datetime :start_time
   t.datetime :end_time

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

I have tried:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :start_time
 serialize :end_time
end
```

But I get `nil` in console when trying `Course.new(start_time: ['2014-12-01 00:00:00 UTC', '2014-11-01 00:00:00 UTC'])`. I have also tried different formats for the dates without success.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: how did it go? have you git it solved?

Answer (score 2):

1. You are passing `String` type objects to `start_time`, which is `DateTime` type.

Do:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :start_time, Array
  serialize :end_time, Array
end
```

and pass appropriate type:

```
Course.create(start_time: [Time.now, Time.now - 1.month])
```

2. You are messing `new` and `create`.

You have to either use:

```
Course.create(start_time: [Time.now, Time.now - 1.month])
```

or

```
course = Course.new
course.start_time = [Time.now, Time.now - 1.month]
course.save
```

Comment: You're serializing stuff into an `Array`, not `DateTime`... no? `DateTime` doesn't have `dump` or `load`.

Comment: all this time I meant array, man - to late, i have to go sleep!